# Transform string in list of lists format to list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a string as the following one and I need to transform it into type list. Fastest way to achieve it in Python?

Thanks

The string to convert into a list of lists:

```
[['"A partir de pistas" es la primera actividad mejor valorada en relación al número de votos', 'R'], ['569 profesores la han importado y en general la han encontrado estupenda', 'R']]
```

Comment: That is a list already. What exactly do you have?

Comment: It is not a list, it is a string

Comment: on which criteria do you want to split your string ?

Comment: The fact that it is not surrounded by quotes outside the brackets says this is not a string. As written, this is a list of lists of srings, e.g. you have shown `x = [[''], ['']]`

Comment: I am new in python so I might be confused. What I want to convert is of class str, does this explain it? @OneCricketeer

Comment: Well, you can see my answer below that addresses what you seem to be asking. Otherwise, it would be best if you showed your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `ast.literal_eval()`

```
>>> x = """[['"A partir de pistas" es la primera actividad mejor valorada en relación al número de votos', 'R'], ['569 profesores la han importado y en general la han encontrado estupenda', 'R']]"""
>>> import ast
>>> type(ast.literal_eval(x))
<class 'list'>
>>> ast.literal_eval(x)[0][0]
'"A partir de pistas" es la primera actividad mejor valorada en relación al número de votos'
```

Comment: That it is actually what I used in my second attempt following this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-a-string-representation-of-list-into-list/ , but I had modified the string previously seems because the resulting list what not the expected one. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: So, this works, or not? Like I said, you should edit your question to show your actual code and what didn't work with this approach

Answer (score -1):

### Depends what you want to do!

If you want to convert each string into a list of individual words, you could use

`listOfStrings = oldString[i].split(' ')`

where ' ' is just a space between two quote marks.

you can then append this listOfStrings variable with each of the lists generated from your source lists:

`listOfStrings.append(oldString[i])`

which will require using a for loop.

### Learning resources:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-convert-string-list/

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: The question wasn't asking for individual words, and this keeps the brackets as part of the split string